# Validations in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

```
[Required]
public string CompanyName { set; get; }

[DataType(DataType.Url)]
public string WebAddress { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
public string Email { get; set; }

[MaxLength(20)]
public Decimal Phone { get; set; }

[Required]
public Decimal AvarageWages {get; set;}
```

Now I need to create field(average wages) with default values for example from 100 - 1000, 1000-2000 and so on. How will i validate that?

Comment: Do you mean the [`RangeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: If that could help but it must be list down

Comment: You should also know that [Required] by default allows empty strings. You might need to add the `AllowEmptyStrings = false` parameter in order to disable empty strings..

Answer (score 3):

For validating range values you might want to use [`Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute:

```
[Range(0, 100)]
public int Value { get; set; }

[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/2011", "1/1/2012", ErrorMessage = "Out of Range!")]
public DateTime DateOfSomething { get; set; }
```

Comment: But I need some list
Wage : 100-1000
       1000-2000 
and client choose, so I need dropdown list of these values

Comment: I don't think you accomplish this the way you think. What I would do is create an enum and use the Display attribute. Something like `Display(Name = "100-1000")`;

Comment: @mikrimouse you want a dropdown list with **a thousand** numbers in it?

Comment: but not thousand, just few

Comment: Is this correct 
public Decimal Avarage {get; set;}
[Display(Name = "100-1000", Order = 0)]
[Display(Name = "1000-2000", Order = 1)]

Comment: And one more validation, i have field where must be minimum two letters. I use [MinLenght(2)] but it doesnt throw me any error on that field when i put one letter.